# Iterate over S4 object slots Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

Is it possible to iterate over `S4` object slots?

So far I was able to come up with this. But I would really like to avoid calling R function `slotNames`. Is there a possibility to do the same on C/C++ level?

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void foo(SEXP x) {
  Rcpp::S4 obj(x);
  Function slotNames("slotNames"); 
  CharacterVector snames = slotNames(obj);
  for (int i = 0; i < snames.size(); i++) {
    SEXP slot = obj.slot(Rcpp::as<std::string>(snames[i]));
    // do something with slot
  }
}
```

Comment: IMO I don't think you are going to incur a significant performance cost from a single call to `slotNames`.

Comment: agree with @nrussell; can you say *why* you want to avoid `slotNames`?

Comment: @ben-bolker I know that one function call will not influence the performance greatly. I need this because I am writing an elaborative tracer for R which writes down arguments of calls. To avoid recursive evaluation it branches to C/C++ where it writes down arguments to a file. So I would want to avoid going back to R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at the [R source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/attrib.c#L1662-L1680), I see stuff like this:

```
/**
 * R_has_slot() : a C-level test if a obj@<name> is available;
 *                as R_do_slot() gives an error when there's no such slot.
 */
int R_has_slot(SEXP obj, SEXP name) {

#define R_SLOT_INIT                         \
    if(!(isSymbol(name) || (isString(name) && LENGTH(name) == 1)))  \
    error(_("invalid type or length for slot name"));       \
    if(!s_dot_Data)                         \
    init_slot_handling();                       \
    if(isString(name)) name = installChar(STRING_ELT(name, 0))

    R_SLOT_INIT;
    if(name == s_dot_Data && TYPEOF(obj) != S4SXP)
    return(1);
    /* else */
    return(getAttrib(obj, name) != R_NilValue);
}
```

Which, I suppose, implies you could drag it out with `getAttrib`.

So, today I learned that S4 slots are actually just special attributes, and these attributes are accessible with `@`. Observe:

```
> setClass("Foo", list(apple = "numeric"))
> foo <- new("Foo", apple = 1)
> foo@apple
[1] 1
> attributes(foo)
$apple
[1] 1

$class
[1] "Foo"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"

> foo@class
[1] "Foo"
attr(,"package")
[1] ".GlobalEnv"
> attr(foo, "bar") <- 2
> foo@bar
[1] 2
```

Hopefully this gives you a place to get started, at least.

Comment: This is however to be considered as an implementation detail and might change without any kind of warning. Although this is unlikely.